Firefox scrolling slow, choppy, and jerky. On Debian with Nvidia GPU
Recently, I noticed that my Firefox scrolling is choppy and laggy. From my experiences with an Intel Macbook Pro from back in 2020ish, I knew that this was likely related to the GPU.
From neofetch, my GPU is Nvidia Geforce RTX 3060. Debian 12, firefox version 128.4.0esr. In Firefox if I go to about:support, under the Graphics section there is nothing about Nvidia.
Nvidia driver is 560.35.03-1,
nvidia-driver/unknown,now 560.35.03-1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 565.57.01-1]
That "upgradable" is interesting, so I did sudo apt update, which says nvidia-driver is updatable, but if I do upgrade it doesn't actually install, and says The following packages have been kept back. I wonder if that has anything to do with it.
If I try to explicitly install the nvidia packages (as opposed to just upgrade with no arguments), it complains that there are unmet dependencies. Maybe Nvidia broke something in their Debian package. (I installed this thru Nvidia's repo which has the newest versions of CUDA and the drivers, not Debian's slightly older repo).

Nvidia renamed several of their packages, so an apt upgrade doesn't properly update the drivers. In this case, Debian falls back to llvmpipe (software rendering). See https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-missing-for-565-drivers-debian-12-packages/311702/4 where others have had this same problem.
I fixed it by completely uninstalling the Nvidia driver and all associated CUDA tools (follow https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#removing-cuda-toolkit), and then reinstalling them by running sudo apt install cuda-toolkit nvidia-driver cuda-drivers.
After rebooting, you may verify that this worked by running glxinfo and checking the renderer string:
$ glxinfo | grep 'renderer string:'
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060/PCIe/SS


I did an apt purge of all nvidia and cuda packages, as recommended by the Debian documentation. Then I rebooted, and then installed the nvidia-driver from the Debian repo (I believe it was contrib/nonfree or something) rather than the Nvidia remote repo. Then rebooted, and firefox scrolled quickly again, and no more lag or choppiness.

I was about to suggest you use the (tested and correctly packaged) drivers available in your distro's repository even if not the most up-to-date version. Using something from 3rd party repos or, worse, Nvidia binaries, tend to produce unexpected and sub-optimal results
